# Django - Unique Together raises error.

Tags: django, django-models, unique-constraint

I am following a book tutorial for Django applications (keyword: TDD, link: [here](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_advanced_forms.html), author: Harry Percival), and I made small changes which now break my code.

#### Test

```
def test_saves_same_game_with_different_players(self):
    player1 = Player.objects.create(name="Player1")
    player2 = Player.objects.create(name="Player2")
    Game.objects.create(player=player1, text="score: other_player")
    game2 = Game.objects.create(player=player2, text="score: other_player")
    game2.full_clean()  # Should not raise.
```

#### Models

```
class Player(models.Model):
  name    = models.TextField(default="")
  objects = models.Manager()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Game(models.Model):
  player = models.ForeignKey(Player, default=None)
  text   = models.TextField(default="", unique=True)

  objects = models.Manager()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.text

  class Meta:
    ordering = ("id",)
    unique_together = ("player", "text")
```

#### Error

```
...
game2 = Game.objects.create(player=player2, text="score: other_player")
...
IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: games_game.text
```

and also with `sqlite`.
The error is with the `unique_together` constraint when creating the second game with the same text.  But this happens even when the players have different names, and even use the name as a string representation.

Would anyone know how to go about this?  Thank you for your patience.
Cheers.

Comment: you have a `unique=True` on your `text` field, And you created two game with same `text` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***text   = models.TextField(default="", unique=True)***

This is where your code is falling because you make text as a unique field.

Comment: Ooooh. So the unique_together doesn't even make it. Thanks!